# Elliptic curve digital signature formats

Tags: signature, pkcs#11, asn.1

There is app built on Java library github/esig/dss and goal is to add remote signatures to PDF files.
Different methods create different formats of signatures. How to convert between them? Especially how to convert pkcs11 format to ASN1?

If PKCS11 is used with smart card then sha256 hash 53EDC760B7A66E1F4D8B0C5715725EE447B79C02F7759C52AD3D36EADD29C10A produces signature like 3066023100ba193a7a87666ebd0f923b7368beeb536b88de47834049d3ed3baf70a23635ac9b73f671beef944b36332754a434f9de023100d4984ef9f4ef61eec28f73cee6f5d8f7a391420c8f21fcc018641f5b54f600458f2d2f823e632ab017fa041e58d48a3f using algorithm ECDSA_SHA256

This is proper ASN1 structure

```
$ openssl asn1parse -inform der -in signature.bin
    0:d=0  hl=2 l= 102 cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  49 prim: INTEGER           :BA193A7A87666EBD0F923B7368BEEB536B88DE47834049D3ED3BAF70A23635AC9B73F671BEEF944B36332754A434F9DE
   53:d=1  hl=2 l=  49 prim: INTEGER           :D4984EF9F4EF61EEC28F73CEE6F5D8F7A391420C8F21FCC018641F5B54F600458F2D2F823E632AB017FA041E58D48A3F
```

However creating signature from CLI using pkcs11-tool the signature length is different so its in different format. How to convert this format to ASN1 der format?

```
$ echo "53EDC760B7A66E1F4D8B0C5715725EE447B79C02F7759C52AD3D36EADD29C10A" |pkcs11-tool -s --slot 1 -p <PIN> |xxd -p -c96
Using signature algorithm ECDSA
3f8c7060430cae99a048618035548bb7449fd9795cad2d8b3b8888fff78593da79cf39a41314a832dd8bae0b5f86c165775fcee045a477809fa8bb3245330abec22443aa8b5bccb775c32238eda1e8ce31a2a84d67b58dc9e3697c3eb8497f43
```

Comment: Paste your first signature in [this ASN.1 decoder](https://lapo.it/asn1js/) to analyze it. It is [ASN.1 DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) for the two integers of the signature, I guess the other is raw bytes without the ASN.1 decoration. The value might be different even if key and hash/data is the same because ECDSA signatures are (usually) randomized. For more on the ASN.1 format see Burt Kaliski's [Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) and [sec1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf) for ECC specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research I found the answer from the BouncyCastle library. byte[] signature is RS encoded signature and the return value will be ASN.1 encoded signature.

```
static byte[] concatenatedRSToASN1DER(final byte[] signature, int signLength) {
    int len = signLength / 2;
    int arraySize = len + 1;

    byte[] r = new byte[arraySize];
    byte[] s = new byte[arraySize];
    System.arraycopy(signature, 0, r, 1, len);
    System.arraycopy(signature, len, s, 1, len);
    BigInteger rBigInteger = new BigInteger(r);
    BigInteger sBigInteger = new BigInteger(s);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        DERSequenceGenerator seqGen = new DERSequenceGenerator(bos);

        seqGen.addObject(new ASN1Integer(rBigInteger.toByteArray()));
        seqGen.addObject(new ASN1Integer(sBigInteger.toByteArray()));
        seqGen.close();
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to generate ASN.1 DER signature", e);
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```